# Is a linear span of finite set from a finite dimensional space topologically closed?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, span

Let $S=\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\} \subset \mathbb{C}^n $ is it true that:

$$ Span (S) = \overline{Span (S)} $$

Must we assume both of the following assumptions? or one of them will be enough?

- The spanning set, S, has a finite number of elements
- The vector space (e.g. $\mathbb{C}^n $) is of finite dimension

Comment: I think that if the vector space is not complex $n$-space, then you first have to say what topology you are using on it, before you can ask questions about sets being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a normed metric space $X$ (such as $\mathbb{C}$) all subspaces spanned by a a finite number of vectors are closed.

I do not know if this is also the case for arbitrary topological vector spaces.